# Add two string in a Combobox

Tags: python, list, combobox, pyqt5, display

I have a graphical interface in which I have a combobox (drop-down list):

In this drop-down list I bring up city names from a 'city' list and the postal code from another 'code' list

here is the code:

```
def changeCombo(self):
    self.ui.comboBox_ChA.clear()
    self.ui.comboBox_ChB.clear()
    for element, code in zip(self.city, self.cityCode):
        self.ui.comboBox_ChA.addItem('{:<30s} {:>10s}'.format(element, str(code)))
```

with this code the display is rather disordered. I wish I had something cleaner.

here it adds me the same space after the names of the city before putting the code. and I would like a display like this:

```
Paris          75
Amsterdam      120
New York City  444 
L.A            845
```

and not a display like this:

```
Paris    75
Amsterdam    120
New York City    444 
L.A    845
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Pandas can help you out. check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html . You can have your City name and respective value as a dictionary and use pandas.DataFrame

Comment: @JenilDave In fact the 'city' and 'code' lists come directly from a dataframe. I used .tolist () to get them.

Comment: @JenilDave But I don't know how to use it to have this.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a UI issue. Running this with a normal print seems to format just as you want. https://repl.it/repls/HotpinkAcademicUnderstanding

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Maybe but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Is that last example the exact output as string or is it how it "appears" in the combobox popup? In that case, are you using a fixed size (monospace) font?

Comment: its how it appears in the combobox @musicamante

Comment: @Isoka05m Could you share a screenshot of it? I believe that you're just facing a font issue (the spaces are correct, but letter widths are different, so you're seeing the difference because of that).